# What are the main differencies between the SVN client and the API?

Tags: svn, svn-api

I'm currently setting up a small continuous integration server for my team. We have recently switched our source code to an SVN server.

I was wondering what are the main differencies between the SVN client from within some scripts or using the svn API from a Python script for example. Why would I choose one or the other, apart from my knowledge of one language or another.

I'm still a the beginning of this project so I think it's the right time for such a question.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SVN client the command-line tool** is what developers use daily. If you only need trivial things like export/checkout/bump-version-and-commit, you can just interface with it in standard Unix way of feeding command line arguments and parsing output. It's the easiest way, and in case something breaks, you can debug a broken operation by repeating it by hand. I know few programs which do that, and they don't seem to have any problems.

**SVN client the API** (libsvnclient) contains programmatic interface for the same commands as those command-line client provides, basically 1:1, but it gives slightly more control over the process. If you expect there will be manipulation of lists/trees of files, sophisticated inclusion/exclusion rules, if you'd like automatic conflict resolution for some files, and other things that may be too complicated to do from bash script or by parsing output, then this API will help. It is very simple to learn and use (simple enough to start using it right away).

**Lower-level SVN API** (like repository/workingcopy access api) gives all control over all aspects of Subversion processes. If you want to use repository as database backend, if you need to do dangerous low-level manipulation on repo/wc (like editing log messages), then it's to be used. It is not simple nor easy to use, even for basic things (in fact, functions from libsvnclient are shortcuts for these APIs, just to make simple things simple). I can't imagine why a CI system would need it.

Comment: That is a very good description, do you have a reference (e.g. SVN red book) for it, or is it homebrew?

Comment: @mliebelt Homebrew. I had a project that saved files inside SVN repository, and I walked my path from invoking `svn` to using libsvnclient.

Comment: @hamstergene Thank you for your instructive reply!